# where is the default folder for theme, icons, and wallpaper?

Tags: desktop-background

I want to make remastered ubuntu for my task. and now I got problem with theme, icon, and wallpaper. actually I've install numix theme and wallpaper and remaster my Ubuntu with REMASTERSYS and after I test it in VM, the numix theme is there. but when I install numix bluish theme and it's icons, the remastered Ubuntu still display numix theme like a previous one. also, someone told me that the default wallpaper folder is at `/usr/share/backgrounds` so I put my costumized wallpaper there so I can use it for my remastered Ubuntu but the wallpaper still numix. do I miss something? sorry for bad english

Comment: Is your question mainly *how* to set the wallpaper or *where* it is stored?

Comment: I'm sorry. I mean I want my wallpaper (i.e gubuntu.png) to be a default wallpaper to my remastered ubuntu called gubuntu.iso and the default theme is numix-bluish and the default icon is compress. I've tried to store gubuntu.png at /usr/share/background and change it in system setting->appearence but my image doesnt appear on it.
I mean, if I activate the wallpaper, can it be default wallpaper in my gubuntu?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Wallpaper

The default wallpaper directory is found at `/usr/share/backgrounds/` and the default wallpaper is called `warty-final-ubuntu.png` so overwrite it to change the default wallpaper easily.

---

#### Icons

For Icons globcally it's the directory `/usr/share/icons/` which typically contains pre-installed themes (shared by all users)

Or locally in your home folder : `~/.icons` which typically contains folders with the themes installed by the user.

Also, many applications have their icons in `/usr/share/pixmaps/`

---

#### Themes

For Themes globally it's the directory `/usr/share/themes/` which typically contains default themes (shared by all users)

Or locally in your home folder : `~/.themes` which typically contains themes installed by the user.

Comment: ??? I'd say better use the key `org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri` then "overwrite" the current wallpaper.

Comment: so, can I just rename my wallpaper's name to the default wallpaper name and move it to /usr/share/backgrounds so it overwrite the default one?

Comment: yes you can do it

Comment: @JacobVlijm I personally play with the xml in  the `contest` dir instead, but i prefer overwriting for newbies

Comment: so where path should I overwrite the default icon and theme?

Comment: according to your used theme, go to /usr/share/theme and search for dir having its name

Comment: @Maythux how to use xml? may be it will be usefull someday :D

Comment: @ariefdharmawan you can change the path of files of wallpapers in the xml file founded under /usr/share/backgrounds/contest directory