# Finding default 16.04 icon pack

Tags: unity, 16.04, icons

Is there any place I can download these directly so I can put them in the /usr/share/icons/ folder? The ones already in my computer have missing images.

Comment: You can extract from http://askubuntu.com/questions/631168/where-is-the-default-folder-for-theme-icons-and-wallpaper

Comment: I know where to find them, its just that I need to reset the icons because the ones already in the /usr/share/icons are not working.

Comment: install some unity tweaker tool, search in google or ask ubuntu.

Comment: The default ones that are already in my computer are broken. I am looking to download new ones for that reason. I just need to download them, then i can put them in /usr/share/icons/ and use unity tweak tool to fix it. If you know where i can download them please tell me.